# Wordpress search result show by priority(first show posts by title)

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

> I have implemented few search filters for custom search. So now i have
> search functions that gets posts by title and custom field. But the
> returned result is show random.
>
> I want to have first shown search result by title, and then by custom
> field. [Search result](http://www.kookse.tv/?s=aardappel)
>
> Is there a way to do that?
>
> The search works great, need just to display them by priority. Here is
> my code for search.

```
add_filter('posts_orderby','my_sort_custom',10,2);
        function my_sort_custom( $orderby, $query ){
            global $wpdb;
        
                if(is_search()){
                
                    $orderby =  $wpdb->prefix."posts.post_type DESC, {$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID ASC";
            }
            return  $orderby;
        }

 function __search_by_title_only( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    global $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $search ) )
        return $search; // skip processing - no search term in query

    $q = $wp_query->query_vars;    
    $n = ! empty( $q['exact'] ) ? '' : '%';

    $search =
    $searchand = '';

    foreach ( (array) $q['search_terms'] as $term ) {
        $term = esc_sql( like_escape( $term ) );
        $search .= "{$searchand}($wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '{$n}{$term}{$n}') ";
        //$searchand = ' AND ';
    }

    if ( ! empty( $search ) ) {
        $search = " AND ({$search}) ";
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() )
            $search .= " AND ($wpdb->posts.post_password = '') ";
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter( 'posts_search', '__search_by_title_only', 1, 2 );




 function posts_join_post_meta( $join, $query ){
 
    global $wpdb;
    
    if( is_search()){
 
        $join .= "
        INNER JOIN
          {$wpdb->postmeta} ON {$wpdb->posts}.ID = {$wpdb->postmeta}.post_id";
 
    }
 
    return $join;
 
}
add_filter( 'posts_join', 'posts_join_post_meta', 2, 2 );




function recipe_search_where( $where, $query ){
 
    global $wpdb;
    if(is_search() ){
        $where .= " OR (
        {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_key = '_recipe_incredients' AND {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value LIKE ('%".$wpdb->escape( get_query_var('s') )."%') ) ";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter( 'posts_where', 'recipe_search_where', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post only **appear** random, because you also sort them by `ID` in this line `{$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID ASC`, try to remove this and sort them only by post type.

If the above method does not work, just write your own plain SQL query and execute it. 
Also important notice: `$wpdb->escape()` function IS deprecated, try to use `$wpdb->prepare()` in order to prevent SQL injection.

Example only:

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("
     SELECT $wpdb->posts
     INNER JOIN $wpdb->postmeta ON $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->postmeta.post_id
     WHERE 1 = 1
     AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_key = %s
     AND $wpdb->postmeta.meta_value LIKE %s
     ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_type DESC
     ",
    '_recipe_incredients', '%'.get_query_var('s').'%')
);
```

See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) for details.